# Widget occupies extra cells

Tags: android, android-widget

I have a 150 x 210 dp widget for xhdpi devices (API 14+). When I add the widget, it occupies more space than it should. It allows me to resize it to occupy smaller space (but WHY it isn't added at the minimum size(like when I resize it)? ) Because I cand resize it to make it smaller, I guess the values I specified for the minimum size are correct... My expectation would be to occupy by default the minimum size I specified, not only when I resize it...

```
<appwidget-provider xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:minWidth="@dimen/recording_widget_min_width"
    android:minHeight="@dimen/recording_widget_min_height"
    android:updatePeriodMillis="86400000"
    android:previewImage="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:initialLayout="@layout/recording_widget_layout"
    android:resizeMode="horizontal|vertical"
    android:widgetCategory="home_screen">    
</appwidget-provider>
```

`values-xhdpi-v14` folder:

```
<resources>
    <dimen name="recording_widget_min_width">150dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="recording_widget_min_height">210dp</dimen>        
</resources>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The minWidth and minHeight are as their name implies, minimums. They are saying the image can be larger than these values, but not smaller.

For example, if you set minWidth and minHeight both to 100, but you supply resource a with an intrinsic size of 50 x 50, it will get stretched to 100 x 100. But if you supply a resource larger than 100 x 100 it will be drawn at it's intrinsic width and height.

For a better understanding, research how android draws views to the screen. In particular look at the use of the MeasureSpecs in onMeasure. A very good explanation of this can be see in the [FlowLayout example at the end of this video lecture by Romain Guy.](https://www.google.com.au/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=4&cad=rja&sqi=2&ved=0CDwQFjAD&url=http://parleys.com/p/514892280364bc17fc56c0e2&ei=19FAUsz1CMKmlQXMr4CACQ&usg=AFQjCNEKqJlh7mK0w-NT6EROlcHwxiWJSA&sig2=JI7HJ2dw-depGNFLiNgHGw)